# Django Rest Framework - Append HostName to response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

when i request an image http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/images/1/ or pass in params for cropping http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/images/1/?height=320&width=420

the response i get is:

```
   {
        "image": "/media/10438039923_2ef6f68348_c.jpg",
        "description": "Description 1",
        "title": "Item 1"
    }
```

while as  on http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/images/

the response is :

```
      {
            "title": "Item 1",
            "description": "Description 1",
            "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/10438039923_2ef6f68348_c.jpg"
        },
        {
            "title": "Item 2",
            "description": "Description 2",
            "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/ALLEY-stock1502.jpg"
        },
```

why isn't easy thumbnails returning the hostname and how can i append the base url to the responses ?

here is my views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Image
from .serializers import ImageSerializer
from easy_thumbnails.files import get_thumbnailer


class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        height = request.query_params.get('height', None)
        width = request.query_params.get('width', None)
        img = self.get_object()
        if height and width:
            options = {'size': (height, width), 'crop': True}
            thumb_url = get_thumbnailer(img.image).get_thumbnail(options).url
        else:
            thumb_url = get_thumbnailer(img.image).url
        serializer = self.get_serializer(img)
        response_dict = {}
        response_dict.update(serializer.data)
        response_dict['image'] = thumb_url
        return Response(response_dict)
```

Comment: Please add serializer code as well.

Answer (score 0):

The host name is stored in the HttpRequest, so you can used it in your response.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Answer (score 0):

As said by Laurent LAPORTE, the host name is stored in the HttpRequest.

But to get it you should not access it directly, rather use:

```
get_host()
```

Otherwise you are bypassing security protections.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/security/#host-header-validation

Answer (score 0):

Open `Settings.py` and scroll down and add

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'UPLOADED_FILES_USE_URL': False
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

or in your settings change `MEDIA_URL` from

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

to

```
MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'
```

Comment: this change causes image url to get not found page. Do you know why?

Comment: maybe there is no image at given url :-)